# Getting ERB files rendered in my browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm struggling with Ruby On Rails to get my ERB files rendered to HTML and get them into my browser. Here is my views/ folder:

[image: views/ folder]

Each subfolder contains views I want to see in my browser, but I don't know how to get them. I'm more used to Express with NodeJs and I would have done a static middleware to set the views/ folder as an asset folder (`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'))` for example)

Now here is my config/routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'devise#index'
end
```

DeviseController.rb:

```
class DeviseController < ApplicationController
    def index

    end
end
```

With this, I can get the views/devise/index.html.erb file from http://localhost:3000/. But now I don't know how to get the other files.

Comment: The questions you are asking are basic and broad. You should complete a basic Rails tutorial like [this one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and then come back with specific questions if you have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise generally treats the "new" route as user login. From terminal run

`rake routes | grep devise` and look for something like:

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                 devise/sessions#new
```

That will tell you the path you need to hit to get your devise new view.

Your routes should look like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users

    root 'users/sign_in'
end
```

You obviously also need a users model set up in your application.
Please see devise documentation [github.com/plataformatec/devise#starting-with-rails](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise#starting-with-rails)

Comment: I only get "root GET  /           devise#index"

Comment: have you added devise to your `config/routes.rb` file? You should have something like `devise_for :users`

Comment: Now I have "rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `devise_for' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x00000000037a6090>"
Is "users" a global variable I don't need to create?

Comment: please see devise documentation https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#starting-with-rails

Comment: I think this is what I needed, I have the all the routes I need now, thanks a lot, if you can edit your post to include this link so I can green check it